# Converting Pixel displacement to radians or mm

Tags: trigonometry

How do i convert a pixel displacement to a displacement in radians, or mm..

I need the formula to convert to a program, for which i know the displacement in pixels, but need it in radians.

Comment: You need more context for this. Pixel-to-mm conversion depends on how many pixels per millimeter you have. And radians are a measure of angle, so you need to know the point about which you measure the angle, and then do some trigonometry.

Comment: Well.. I know the horizontal view being 45 degrees. and  lets say i want to look at a depth of 1 meter.